# Moving wp-admin folder to a different host in a multisite environment

Tags: multisite, wp-admin

Current Multisite setup:

- First site: `www.site1.com`
- Second site: `subdomain.site1.com`
- Admin: `www.site1.com/wp-admin/`

How to move wp-admin to a different host, which is accessed via a domain say `admin.site1.com`?